# BUILD FAILED after installing @react-native-firebase/storage

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, firebase-storage, npm-install, react-native-firebase

My react native app worked perfectly fine, but then I did run `npm install @react-native-firebase/storage` followed by `cd ios` and `pod install`.

After that, an error occurred so I add the following lines into my Podfile

```
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
```

and I did run `pod install` again. It worked.

Now I run `npm run ios` and the following error occurred

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/settasit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Saimai-foaejnvgtcqtzfgskjrmfysporda/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBDatabase.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNFBDatabaseReferenceModule.o /Users/settasit/ReactNative/Saimai/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database/ios/RNFBDatabase/RNFBDatabaseReferenceModule.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNFBDatabase' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Can anyone tell me now to solve this problem please?

This is my Podfile if it might help

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '14.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Saimai' do
  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'SaimaiTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

Answer (score 1):

Add a comment to a previous answer.. The newest versions of firebase/storage demand on statement "use_frameworks! :linkage => :static", which is incompatible with Flipper. When you use this approach, then you should disable this line  "# you should disable the next line.
:flipper_configuration => flipper_config," in your Podfile. Only this way you can successfully build the IOS app. Another option is to downgrade your version of firebase/storage to v14 and lower

Comment: you better splits the answer into paragraphs. It helps the answer easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` just before `pod 'Firebase...`

Comment: I did that and `pod install` again. It installed `ReactCommon 0.71.3`. But when I did `npm run ios`, it failed again with an error `The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/settasit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData... (in target 'FlipperKit' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)`